# What boolean algebra simplification is applied in this Shannon's expansion?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Found this question about Shannon's expansion. While I am trying to follow its logic, found one super convenience simplification used. Can we do this in general while dealing with boolean algebra? or only in Shannon's expansion?

Can we just turn b+d into 1 while we have (+)⋅1 previously in the equation?

Also + into 1 while we have (+)⋅1 previously in the equation?

Picture from that question:

[image]

Comment: Please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_expansion_theorem

Comment: Thank you for the link, but at the same time. wonder if you read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They applied the *Absorption Law 1* from [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). According to this law, the following is true:

$$x \land (x \lor y) = x$$

Sometimes the operator "$\land$" is replaced by multiplication, and also the operator "$\lor$" - by addition. That's why:

$$(b+d) \cdot 1 \cdot (b+c+d+e+f)=(b+d) \cdot ((b+d)+c+e+f)=b+d$$
$$1 \cdot (b+c) \cdot (b+c+d+e+f)=(b+c) \cdot ((b+c)+d+e+f)=b+c$$

Yes, appearance of $1$ in $(1+c+e+f)$ and $(1+d+e+f)$ terms looks strange to me as well - may be, they teach this kind of simplifications this way, it's difficult to say without looking at your textbook.

(By the way, pictures like this aren't welcomed on this site)